# How to scrape data after clicking button

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from website with beautiful soup, but to scrape all content, I have to click button

```
<button class="show-more">view all 102 items</button>
```

to load every item. I have heard that it could by done with selenium, but it means that i have to open browser with script, and then scrape the data. Are there any other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes... Why not try selenium?

Comment: Link the website, probably much easier way than using `selenium`

Comment: https://bandcamp.com/leczo/wishlist, im trying to scrape  all albums names and links to them, but i have to click button on bottom, to load every of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same API endpoint the page does which returns all the info in json form. Set a records return count higher than the total expected number. I show parsing out the album titles/urls from the json. You can explore response [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b9062fa1620c4c42828591a947d2aab8). You can find this endpoint in the browser network tab when refreshing the url you supplied.

```
import requests

data = {"fan_id":1812622,"older_than_token":"1557167238:2897209009:a::","count":1000}
r = requests.post('https://bandcamp.com/api/fancollection/1/wishlist_items', json = data).json()
details = [(item['album_title'], item['item_url']) for item in r['items']]
print(details)
```